# PHP: Big Array Iteration

Tags: php, arrays, iteration

I've been having this problem when I iterate on an array that I get from reading a XLS File, it suddenly stops at line 9700 without getting any error when I have a file with 19000 rows.

First I though it was the memory or time execution but that's not the case, I modified the memory limit to 2GB and the time execution 90 secs.

This is the code I'm using ....

```
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
$data->setOutputEncoding('CP1251');
data->read(basename($_FILES['excel_file']['name']));
echo $data->sheets[0]['numRows']."<br><br>";
$i=0;
$n = $data->sheets[0]['numRows'];
echo $n."<br>";
foreach ($data->sheets[0]['cells'] as $cell) {
   echo "$i - ".$cell[1].", ";
   $i++;
}
```

Comment: There has to be an error or some explanation for it quitting early. Did you check the error logs?

Comment: Perhaps you're not showing all errors

Comment: Try to run your script from bash, if run good from bash that mean that the browser go in time out

Comment: Are you sure the page has finished loading? PHP may have simply dumped the buffer to the browser and then went on to keep processing the rest of the items.

Comment: I'm using error_reporting(E_ALL) and does not show any errors.

Comment: If I print_r the array it shows all the info but when I did the foerach it stops at 9000 record

Comment: Just wondering what do you get if you `echo count($data->sheets[0]['cells']);`

Comment: How long after start does it die, approximately in seconds?

Comment: If i do the count I got the 19000 records and took only a couple seconds to run

Comment: The script consumes only 18MB when it reach line 9796 after it stops without any reason.